# App remains in "most recent list" after killing it

Tags: android

I'm killing my app like so:

`android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());`

but after i do it, my app still appears in the "Most recent apps" list from where i can reload it. Does that mean it's still in memory? Or is that list just a "snapshot" of the app, the actual process in fact died ?

Comment: I don't care what the reason is for why you're seeing what you're seeing, all I'd say is don't use `killProcess(...)` - it's a hack and `Android` anti-pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use :

android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());

Then your process is killed from active processes

But Recent Application window shows history of navigation so it will capture your application whether it is killed or not.

> For example, You have opened X app which produces FATAL Exception,
>   Force Close. So this X will be killed by android system but still it
>   will be visible in Recent Application window

I think you do not want to exclude your app from Recent Application list window, it is not advisable also because only certain system apps like Launcher use this thing and they specify `android:excludeFromRecent` flag in application

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `android:excludeFromRecents` in manifest to exclude it from recent activity

Comment: And will that only exclude it if the process is dead? 'cause I still want it to appear when it's still in memory ...